# Title: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is @Composable, why can't I remember mutableStateOf Composable Function directly?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-function-type

I can have

```
val composeFunction = remember { mutableStateOf ({}) }
```

I can have

```
val composeFF = @Composable { Text("ABC") }
val composeFunction = remember { mutableStateOf (composeFF) }
```

Why can't I have

```
val composeFunction = remember { mutableStateOf (@Composable { Text("ABC") }) }
```

It errors out state

```
Internal Error occurred while analyzing this expression 
(Please use the "
 
" icon in the bottom-right corner to report this error):
 
jar:file:/Applications/Android%20Studio.app/Contents/lib/platform-impl.jar!/general/error.svg
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is @Composable () -> Unit but () -> Unit was expected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the type?

```
val composeFunction = remember { mutableStateOf<@Composable () -> Unit> (@Composable { Text("ABC") }) }
```

Looks like the compiler cannot infer an ordinary function to something that is supplied with a `@Composable` annotation

**Update**:

It turns out `@Composable` annotation actually modifies the function type, similar to what suspend modifier does.

Based on this [arcticle](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd),

> An important thing to note is that Compose is not an annotation
> processor. Compose works with the aid of a Kotlin compiler plugin in
> the type checking and code generation phases of Kotlin: there is no
> annotation processor needed in order to use compose. This annotation
> more closely resembles a language keyword. A good analogy is Kotlin’s
> suspend keyword.

furthermore,

> The important point here is that when you annotate a function type
> with @Composable you’re changing its type: the same function type
> without the annotation is not compatible with the annotated type.
> Also, suspend functions require a calling context, meaning that you
> can only call suspend functions inside of another suspend function.

Comment: Didn't work for me..

Comment: @Pexers hard to say why, but personally these kinds of issues are the things you have to look for regarding versions and compatibilities, my `kotlin` and `compose` versions are almost up to date, sometimes an IDE `invalidate cache~restart` would do the trick, other than these aside from the type inference, I have no idea